# how can i use obj.sendkeys Method based on output of previous statement executed in command line through VBScript

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, automation

Batch File

```
`cscript test.vbs`
```

VbsCRIPT file namesd Test

```
`set obj=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
obj.SendKeys "cd  c:\users\hp\documents"
Wscript.sleep 200
obj.SendKeys {ENTER}
obj.SendKeys "dir"
Wscript.sleep 200`
```

**this is where code is supposed to decide**

`obj.SendKeys "xcopy c:\users\hp\documents\today D:\MyBackups /E"
    Wscript.sleep 200`

i want to execute next statement only if the folder **today** is present in the list which comes after typing dir

so the main question is how can i make the system decide based on the output of previous statement

this is the basic part only.
Every day's backup takes different time to copy based on size.
I want to wait for the next statement to execute only after previous one is executed successfully
i.e if files are copied successfully then execution of the file should proceed

any help is appreciated
*please ignore syntactic error. i made it working in my system somehow and this question is posted through phone when i didn't had my system*

Comment: Why not use FileSystemObject, check if dir exists then perform xcopy

Comment: no its not going to work in this case....
the only condition i have to work with that can i sendKeys according to the output of previous command executed

Comment: Why not use a batch script for a task that essentially consists of running external commands? Why are you running a batch script to run a VBScript that types batch/CMD commands into a CMD window? `if exist c:\users\hp\documents\today xcopy c:\users\hp\documents\today D:\MyBackups /E`